# Where to put resource-action-mappins in liferay maven portlet

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay 6.1 GA3.

My resource-action-mappings in an ant-based liferay portlet are in

```
WEB-INF/src/resource-actions/default.xml
```

with

```
resource.actions.configs=resource-actions/default.xml
```

in my portlet.properties files.

How does this change in a maven-based portlet ?
I don't like the idea of non source files in the src folder.

Many thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put it to portlet/src/main/resources/resource-actions/default.xml and portlet/src/main/resources/portlet.properties